# Erro no Retorno da API do Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Segue meu cenário para melhor entendimento:

- Tenho a View Home que chama a View Login, por `pushViewController`.
- Na minha View Login, fica o botão customizado do Facebook que está chamando normalmente a página de autorização do facebook;
- Mas o retorno da tela de permissão do facebook está me causando problemas, ao invés dele retornar para minha View Login, está retornando para minha View Home;

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem na log: `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <XXX.LoginTableViewController: 0x14eba93d0>`.

Esse é minha action para o login, não vai ficar desta forma, mas fui simplificando o máximo para tentar achar o problema:

```
@IBAction func facebookButton() {
    let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
    login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"],
                                   fromViewController: self) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("deu merda")
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            print("cancelou")
        } else {
            print("login")
        }
    }
}
```

Obs: na mesma View Login eu tenho o botão de login do Twitter, que está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: O app está utilizando da lib [ENSwiftSideMenu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu) e vi todo AlertView está utilizando do `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. Se tirar eles dão o mesmo erro da view do facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   "LoginTableViewController"

Esse erro acontece porque em algum momento do seu código você está fazendo `pushViewController` mais de uma vez ao mesmo tempo.

Por exemplo: Você cria um botão no Storyboard e liga um `segue` nesse botão para outra tela, e também cria um método `IBAction clickBotao:` que chama a outra tela também. Nesse caso você vai ter 2 *pushs* pra mesma tela e isso causa esse erro.

Verifique se quando ele retorna do callback do Facebook ele não está fazendo algo como expliquei acima.

Comment: Eu consigo ver a hierarquia de navegação para identificar isso? Minha navegação para a LoginTableViewController é feita por push pois ela é chamada por várias views diferentes.

Comment: Você pode ver a hierarquia pelo `Storyboard` caso esteja usando ele, ou se não, pode colocar um `breakpoint` em cada lugar que faz um *push* da LoginTableViewController para ver como está a sua hierarquia.

Comment: Não encontrei nada do tipo no meu código, mas o app está utilizando da lib ENSwiftSideMenu. E vi que não consigo colocar o login do facebook em nenhum view que não seja as que estão no menu da lib.

Comment: Era esse mesmo meu problema, como estou apenas dando manutenção no código fui que rever todo o código pronto e descobri que durante a montagem do menu do SNSwiftSideMenu o antigo desenvolvedor fez umas gambiarras que executava duas _pushs_!